# Rust multithreading support

Tags: linux, multi-threaded, rust

I want to run a Minecraft/rust server on a machine that has Linux (raspberry pi OS but I can change this) is there a way to run the server with multiple cores? (I would start the server in terminal if that helps)

Comment: How have you determined the server isn’t already multi-threaded.  Most applications that support multithreaded operations automatically determine how many threads the system supports and scale to that number.

Comment: I have just seen that rust servers run on a single thread on stack exchange and overflow